# Selecting current selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I created a basic pricing calculator with selectboxes and div buttons. The problem is, that when I click on the button, it selects all selectboxes in my code. I need to specify only one, where I clicked recently.

```js
$(".prev").click(function() {
    $('.val option:selected').prev().attr('selected', 'selected');
});

$(".next").click(function() {
    $('.val option:selected').next().attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

```css
.prev, .next {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #6c6c6c;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="calc">
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="prev"></div>
            <select class="val">
                <option selected>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>6</option>
            </select>
            <div class="next"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="prev"></div>
            <select class="val">
                <option selected>2</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>8</option>
                <option>16</option>
                <option>32</option>
            </select>
            <div class="next"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="prev"></div>
            <select class="val">
                <option selected>0</option>
                <option>50</option>
                <option>100</option>
            </select>
            <div class="next"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="prev"></div>
            <select class="val">
                <option selected>0</option>
                <option>50</option>
                <option>100</option>
                <option>200</option>
            </select>
            <div class="next"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="prev"></div>
            <select class="val">
                <option selected>0</option>
                <option>200</option>
                <option>500</option>
                <option>1000</option>
            </select>
            <div class="next"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="prev"></div>
            <select class="val">
                <option selected>Linux</option>
                <option>Windows</option>
            </select>
            <div class="next"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `$(this)` to get clicked `<div>`.
2. use `.siblings('select')` or `.siblings('.val')` to get that `select`.
3. use `.find('option:selected').next()/.prev()` to get next/prev option to be selected.
4. use `.prop('selected', true)` to select it.

```js
$(".prev").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('select').find('option:selected').prev().prop('selected', true);
});

$(".next").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('select').find('option:selected').next().prop('selected', true);
});
```

```css
.prev, .next {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #6c6c6c;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="calc">
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="prev"></div>
            <select class="val">
                <option selected>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>6</option>
            </select>
            <div class="next"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="prev"></div>
            <select class="val">
                <option selected>2</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>8</option>
                <option>16</option>
                <option>32</option>
            </select>
            <div class="next"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="prev"></div>
            <select class="val">
                <option selected>0</option>
                <option>50</option>
                <option>100</option>
            </select>
            <div class="next"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="prev"></div>
            <select class="val">
                <option selected>0</option>
                <option>50</option>
                <option>100</option>
                <option>200</option>
            </select>
            <div class="next"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="prev"></div>
            <select class="val">
                <option selected>0</option>
                <option>200</option>
                <option>500</option>
                <option>1000</option>
            </select>
            <div class="next"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="prev"></div>
            <select class="val">
                <option selected>Linux</option>
                <option>Windows</option>
            </select>
            <div class="next"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `this`

```
$(".prev").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".val option:selected").prev().attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```